# Cannot init Facebook Payment, "Account id missing" Error 1383056

Tags: facebook, payment, facebook-apps

When the "Buy" button is pressed the following error appears:

error_code: 1383056

error_message: "Account id missing.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : appId,
          status     : true,
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });

        function buy() {
          var obj = {
            method: 'pay',
            action: 'purchaseitem',
            product: productLink
          };

          FB.ui(obj, function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          });
        }

        document.getElementById('pay').onclick = function() {buy()};
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
      }(document));
    </script>
```

The error occurs both in test and active app. The code example was taken there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/payments/dialog/

Product code:

```
<html>
 <head prefix=
    "og: http://ogp.me/ns# 
     fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
     product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    <meta property="og:type"                   content="og:product" />
    <meta property="og:title"                  content="IE Coupon" />
    <meta property="og:plural_title"           content="IE Coupons" />
    <meta property="og:image"                  content="http://forestowner.com/game/img/crystal_ico.png" />
    <meta property="og:description"            content="Interactive coupons" />
    <meta property="og:url"                    content="http://forestowner.com/game/crystal.html" />
    <meta property="product:price:amount"      content="0.00"/>
    <meta property="product:price:currency"    content="USD"/>
  </head>
</html>
```

What can be the reason of the error?

Comment: I have the same problem, did  you fix it ?

Comment: As far as I can understand the root of the problem is in  callback-files, which should be indicated in canvas payments. Make sure that they send back a proper result and that will fix it.

Comment: Any luck with that error?